# Pandas - using str.contains to match string

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have a column in my pandas df that looks like this:

```
Cycle 1 (0 h)
           A
           B
           C
Cycle 2 (0 h 43 min)
           A
           B
           C
```

I'm trying to match 'Cycle' and extract the digits. Ideally, I'd like for my output to look like this:

```
       0
       A
       B
       C
      0,43
       A
       B
       C
```

I've tried:

```
df['1'] = df['1'].str.contains('Cycle', regex=True).str.extract('(\d+)')
```

But it gets rid of the Cycle line completely - I thought that after extracting the digits I could use `str.split()` and retain only the pertinent numbers which I could then separate by a comma. But I can't seem to extract the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```py
rx = r'^Cycle\s+\d+\s+\((\d+)(?:\s*\w+\s*(\d+))?.*'
df['1'] = df['1'].str.replace(rx, lambda x: f'{x.group(1)},{x.group(2)}' if x.group(2) else x.group(1), regex=True)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6Ahe0K/2). Here, the `^Cycle\s+\d+\s+\((\d+)(?:\s*\w+\s*(\d+))?.*` pattern is searched for and if there is  a match, it is replaced with Group 1 + `,` + Group 2 contents, or only Group 1 value depending on whether Group 2 matched or not.

*Details*:

- `^`  - start of string
- `Cycle` - a word
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\d+` - one or more digits
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `\(` - a `(` char
- `(\d+)` - Group 1 (`\1`): one or more digits
- `(?:\s*\w+\s*(\d+))?` - an optional non-capturing group matching an optional sequence of

  - `\s*\w+\s*` - one or more word chars enclosed with one or more whitespace chars
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2 (`\2`): one or more digits
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

If Group 2 matched, the replacement is Group 1 + `,` + Group 2 values, else, it is only Group 1 value.

Pandas test:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'1': ['Cycle 1 (0 h)', 'Cycle 1 (0 h 48 min)']})
rx = r'^Cycle\s+\d+\s+\((\d+)(?:\s*\w+\s*(\d+))?.*'
df['1'].str.replace(rx, lambda x: f'{x.group(1)},{x.group(2)}' if x.group(2) else x.group(1), regex=True)
# => 0       0
# => 1    0,48
# => Name: 1, dtype: object
```

Comment: Wow, the regex site is so cool! Thanks for the help.

Comment: @HenryEcker Fixed, I had to use a conditional replacement.